# Powershell script working in windows 10 but not 7?

Tags: powershell

I don't know whats causing this, the script seems to work on Windows 10 but not on Windows 7. The function that's creating a problem is `limpia()` which cleans the text.

The new file gets generated, but it seems that the `creplace` or the `replace` are not working in Windows 7 - so I get the same file but with just a different name.

Any help is appreciated.

```
$root = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$folder = 'C:\Users\JuanMa\Desktop\UNB\TMP\'
$filter = 'FACT_TEMPORAL.TXT'

Write-Host "EL ROOT ES $root" -fore white

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    NotifyFilter          = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

    Write-Host "The file '$name' at '$path'was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore white
    limpia
    printpdf
    borrar
    renombra
}

function limpia() {
    write-host "FUNCION LIMPIA ARCHIVO TXT" -fore white 
    $a = get-content $root\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.txt | 
        Foreach-Object { ($_ -creplace '^[.! pÿ>i@]{1,}') } |
        Foreach-Object { ($_ -creplace '^0 {2,}') } |
        Foreach-Object { ($_ -replace '>', '') } |
        Foreach-Object { ($_.TrimEnd() )}  | where {$_ -ne ""} |
        set-content $root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt
}

function printpdf() {
    write-host "FUNCION IMPRIMIR A PDF" -fore white 
    start-process -filepath "$root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt" -verb print 
}

function borrar() {
    write-host "FUNCION BORRAR" -fore white 
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    Remove-Item $root\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.txt
}

function renombra() {
    write-host "FUNCION RENOMBRAR ARCHIVO" -fore white   
    Get-Item $root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {("print-" + '{0:yyyyMMddhhmmss}{1}' -f (Get-Date), ".txt")}
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error output? Whats in there?

Comment: no errors whatsoever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Windows 10** gets regular updates via MS update center, it currently uses PowerShell version:

```
PS C:\Users\user> $psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.228
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.228
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

**Windows 7** comes with version 2.0 out of the box. As you can see in the answer right [here](https://superuser.com/questions/650814/what-version-of-powershell-comes-with-windows-7):

```
PS C:\Users\user> get-host


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : 61ef8a3b-0212-4743-87a1-eb2c00fb1e29
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserI
                   nterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

My suggestion is to check the compatibility of the commands used *-and* either:

1. Upgrade the powershell version.

*-or*

2. Rewrite the function using compatible commands.

EDIT:
My second suggestion is to try out .NET tools, whenever powershell modules fail me. In this case, I would try replacing -creplace wih this:

```
function limpia() {
    $regex = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]
    write-host "FUNCION LIMPIA ARCHIVO TXT" -fore white 
    $a = get-content $root\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.txt | 
        Foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '^[.! pÿ>i@]{1,}', '') } |
        Foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '^0 {2,}', '') } |
        Foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '>', '') } |
        Foreach-Object { ($_.TrimEnd() )}  | Where-Object {$_ -ne ""} |
        set-content $root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt
}
```

I have not checked the patterns, you will have to do that by your self. Since I do not know the file structure, I can not give you a better answer, it seems like you could cleanup the file using only one foreach loop and one regexp.

Comment: I upgraded powershell and it's still not working. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: I think the problem is an encoding one. The txt that I get in the win 7 it's different from the one in windows 10. So I need to change the code to delete whatever junk text is generated despite the computer is being used. Any help on this?

Comment: Could you provide me with FACT_TEMPORAL.txt by any chance?

Comment: @JuanManuelSanchez I hav eupdated my answer, try it out

Comment: It worked, sadly the output is giving me more weird character, this is a sample

!! !           PESCATORE
!           LEMON SPICE S.R.L.
      600 SUR DE MULTIPLAZA ESCAZU
              3-102-599284
     TEL: 2289-8010 FAX: 2289-5129
          INFO@PESCATORECR.COM

     ------------FACTURA-----------
!0   Mesa M09 (R)
!! NUMERO : 0068448  
!Mesa # : M09           Fecha: 01/10/2018

Comment: If my tips worked for you, marking my answer would be nice of you. Now, what is the weird character? You could say that about any of them, its a chaos.

Comment: I believe you should be able to mark your own answaer as answered, that means marking one of the responses as accepted. The little green flag between the up and down chevrons. That does not work for you?

Comment: I just make it to work. So thanks again. Let me see the answering part...Thanks a lot man !

Answer (score 0):

empty strings in Powershell like "" is not so good try with $null.
And look at the regular Expression Syntax in Powershell, maybe than it should work.

Comment: I think the problem is an encoding one. The txt that I get in the win 7 it's different from the one in windows 10. So I need to change the code to delete whatever junk text is generated despite the computer is being used.

Comment: Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot everybody. After upgrading and making the changes suggested in the limpia function its now able to work correctly.

The function is

```
function limpia() 
{
    $regex = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]
    write-host "FUNCION LIMPIA ARCHIVO TXT" -fore white 
    $a = get-content $root\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.txt | 
        Foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '^[.! pÿ>i@]{1,}', '') } |
        Foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '^0 {2,}', '') } |
        Foreach-Object { $regex::Replace($_, '>', '') } |
        Foreach-Object { ($_.TrimEnd() )}  | Where-Object {$_ -ne ""} |
        set-content $root\UNB\FINAL_TEXTO\FACT_FINAL.txt

}
```

Thanks a lot !